# Computing the exterior derivative of a wedge product

Tags: differential-geometry

How can we prove the following relation for differentiating the wedge product of a p-form $\alpha_p$ and a q-form $\beta_q$?

$$d(\alpha_p\wedge\beta _q)=d\alpha_p\wedge\beta_q+(-1)^{p}\alpha_p\wedge d\beta_q$$

Comment: There are many equivalent ways of organizing the definitions that go into that, and the answer to your question depends on which one of them has been used.

Comment: I want to prove the above relation in simple way by using the definition of exterior derivative and wedge product

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It suffices to take $\alpha = f\, dx^{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{i_p}$ and $\beta=g\,dx^{j_1}\wedge \dots\wedge dx^{j_q}$. Then $\alpha\wedge\beta = fg\, dx^{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{i_p}\wedge dx^{j_1}\wedge \dots\wedge dx^{j_q}$. Write out the product rule, and then keep track of the switches you must do to get $d\alpha\wedge\beta$ and $\alpha\wedge d\beta$ appearing in your formula.

**EDIT:** Doing the exercise for you: 
\begin{align*}
d(\alpha\wedge\beta) &= d(fg\, dx^{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{i_p}\wedge dx^{j_1}\wedge \dots\wedge dx^{j_q}) \\ 
&= (g\,df + f\,dg) \wedge (dx^{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{i_p}\wedge dx^{j_1}\wedge \dots\wedge dx^{j_q}) \\
&= (df\wedge dx^{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{i_p})\wedge (g\,dx^{j_1}\wedge \dots\wedge dx^{j_q}) + \\
&\qquad (f\,dg)\wedge (dx^{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{i_p}\wedge dx^{j_1}\wedge \dots\wedge dx^{j_q}) \\
&= d\alpha \wedge\beta + (-1)^p (f\,dx^{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{i_p})\wedge (dg\wedge dx^{j_1}\wedge \dots\wedge dx^{j_q}) \\
&= d\alpha\wedge\beta + (-1)^p \alpha\wedge d\beta.
\end{align*}

Comment: Here is what I did like you said-$$\alpha_p = f\, dx^{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{i_p}$$ $$\beta_q=g\,dx^{j_1}\wedge \dots\wedge dx^{j_q}$$ Then,$$\alpha_p\wedge\beta_q = fg\, dx^{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{i_p}\wedge dx^{j_1}\wedge \dots\wedge dx^{j_q}$$ Now, how to apply product rule and the exterior derivative

Comment: Also, we also know the formula for the wedge product $$\alpha_p\wedge\beta_q=(-1)^{pq}\beta_q\wedge\alpha_p$$ Now, how to proceed from here if I want to prove the above relation through this

Comment: Now,$$\alpha_p\wedge\beta_q=(fdg+gdf)dx^{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{i_p}\wedge dx^{j_1}\wedge \dots\wedge dx^{j_q}$$ Now, how to proceed from here.

Comment: Match up the two terms to the two terms in the formula.

Comment: Sorry, but still lost. Can you please further elaborate with an edit to the answer.

Comment: Why there is (-1)^p in the second last term

Comment: Switching $dg$ with the $p$-form $dx^{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{i_p}$.

Comment: Why is there no additional $(-1)^p$ term in the first expression $da \wedge \beta$ when you switch $g$ with the same $p$-form?

Comment: @noamchomsky $g$ is a $0$-form.