# Question on theorem 10.20 Walter Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

We need these definitions for the theorem:
[image]
[image]

> **Theorem 10.20**
>
> (a)If $\omega, \lambda $ are $k-$ and $m-$ forms, respectively of class $C^{1}$ in $E$, then $$d(\omega \land \lambda)=(d\omega)\land \lambda + (-1)^{k}\omega \land d\lambda$$
>
> (b) If $\omega$ is of class $C^{1}$, then $d^{2} \omega=0$

[image]

Hence it's said that ( read the proof on the photo)
$d(\omega \land \lambda)$ = ($df \land dx_I$)$\land$ ($g dx_J$) + (${-1}^k$)($fdx_I$)$\land$($dg \land dx_J$) . ( mark this equality by ($\star$))

I couldn't understand how do we get the ($\star$).

I would be grateful for any kind of help.

Comment: There is a lot of text there. I don't see the star.

Comment: @JohnDouma what do you mean?

Comment: I did't see your starred equation in the text. I finally found it four lines above the bottom of the text of the book but this is difficult to read. Also, the author is referencing $(59)$ and $(60)$ which is probably necessary to understand this.

Comment: @JohnDouma i've added these things. now can you answer?

Comment: You can find this precise question many times on this site. For example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1164823/differential-geometry-wedge-product) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1983260/exterior-derivative-of-wedge-product/1985000#1985000).

Comment: baby Rudin isn't the best place to be learning differential forms.  In fact I'd stop with baby Rudin after Ch9.  For manifolds and differential forms I'd use Tu (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4419-7400-6).  For Lebesgue integration I'd use Axler (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-33143-6).